# Should I make my repo private for building a website for a business?

Tags: javascript, web, mean-stack

I am building a website for a freelance gig (for a family member) and it is a website for a new business to display their showroom and current inventory of one-of-a-kind items. I do not believe there will be any sensitive data on the website. There will be a admin page for admins login and add items and lots of pictures.

My first question is: Is it okay to use a public github repo? (I am trying to build up my portfolio) Or would it be better to use a private repo on bitbucket?

My second question is: Is it ridiculous to build this app/website from scratch with the MEAN stack? I know it will take some time to get everything set up and I have some experience building MEAN stack apps. Is the MEAN stack a reasonable solution for this project?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I program with the MEAN a lot and i find it very suitable to do just about anything. I build all my MEAN projects from scratch. Yes it will take longer but it is my personal preference. For this project i think MEAN is very good especially if you already have experience with it. You are going to want to do your research when storing images with Mongo. Mongo does not handle large amounts of data good and files and images eat up a lot but there are ways to store images properly. Research GridFS

If you are trying to build a portfolio then make the repo public. If there is sensitive information in your code such as token secrets, passwords, auth_tokens. Then you can use environment variables to store those. For example:

if you have:

auth_token = 12345;

On your computer, you can set an environment variable for this and then use it like this

auth_token = process.env.yourVariable //Not working code just an example

or before you publish your repo change the values

auth_token = "your auth token"

Some things to consider when publishing repo:

- Is this web site for someone else? maybe they don't want code in public
- Is this website unique idea? maybe you do not want people to steal it

Git offers private repos and if you are a student then they are free.

Comment: Just a quick addendum: if you're going to change a private repo into a public one, be careful with sensitive information that is available through project history. One can clone the repo and checkout at any previous commit that might contain this kind of info. Consider creating a new repository, without the history.

Answer (score 1):

In response to your first question (Is it okay to use a public github repo?):
If you are going to reference any sort of private keys or passwords in your repo, you should ensure that you don't expose them in your public repo.  You should also speak with the family member to ensure they're okay with you sharing the source as part of your portfolio.

Comment: Thank you both for the info I appreciate your responses! I will reach out to my family member to make sure they are okay with it being public but I think the public repo is the way to go.